# How to split a patch in MQ by files within the Workbench (no command line)?

Tags: mercurial, patch, tortoisehg, workbench, mercurial-queue

The Mercurial Workbench within TortoiseHG allows a graphical use of many mercurial functions. I have a patch sitting in a mercurial queue from which I want to extract some files to another separate patch.

I found a [solution here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqTutorial#Split_a_patch_into_multiple_patches) for the command line approach:

Gaol: End up with OP=P1 + P2, where OP=Original Patch, P1=Patch 1, P2=Patch 2

Solution:

```
hg qpush OP
hg qrefresh <paths to keep> to replace OP with P1, including only the paths you named. The other changes will remain as uncommitted changes in the working directory.
hg qnew -f P2 to pick up those changes.
```

I simply cannot figure out how to do this within the workbench and would be glad if someone could teach me how to accomplish this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the refresh button in TortoiseHg it acts on the ticked items in the list so to do what you ask you follow the following steps:

1. Click on your patch OP in the top list
2. Untick the the files that you want to go into the second patch on the list of changed files on the left
3. Click the refresh button on the right
4. Click on the working directory entry on the top list to see the rest of the files
5. Tick all the files on the list of changes on the left
6. Click on the new patch button on the right (click on the little down arrow on the commit button if that it's the active button to select the new patch button)

Obviously, enter any commit messages as required.